# Modifying Columns In Zend Framework Select

Tags: zend-framework

In a Zend_Db_Select object, I am doing a join to get user information for some data records.  For the join is on a userId, I would like to combine the user first and last name into a single column of name.

Basically I am looking to have something similar to this:

```
$table = array('u' => 'User');
$condition = 'u.id = t.id';
$columns = array('UserName' => 'u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName')
$select->joinLeft($table, $condition, $columns);
```

I have tried using a Zend_Db_Expr with no luck and the above does not work.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It seems that you've a trailing single quot here ---> 'u.FirstName

Comment: If I remember it good, concatenation isn't a standard operation. So, every DBMS use it in a different way (for example ||). What DBMS underlay Zend_Db? Have you checked that you're using the right concatenation method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zend_Db_Expr` is the way to go, but you'll have better luck if you use the database's concatenation function. Assuming MySQL:

```
$columns = new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName') AS name")
```

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't using the proper concatenation function when creating the Zend_Db_Expr.